# How do you add an attribute to an Unicode string in Swift?

Tags: unicode, swift

How do you add attribute to a UNICODE string in Swift?

NSMakeRange seems to expect String in bytes for a variable byte length UNICODE string.

Any way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

```
var s:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "வாங்க வாங்க வணக்கமுங்க")
s.string[0...2]
s.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value:UIColor(red:0.0, green:1.0, blue:0.0, alpha:1.0), range:NSMakeRange(0,3))
```

UPDATED EXAMPLE:

```
let text = "வாங்க வாங்க வணக்கமுங்க"
var startOfWord = advance(text.startIndex, 4)
var endOfWord = advance(startOfWord, 3)
var highlightRange = startOfWord..<endOfWord
text[startOfWord..<endOfWord]

let attrText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text)
attrText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value:UIColor(red:0.0, green:1.0, blue:0.0, alpha:1.0), range:highlightRange)
```

How do construct NSRange from swift Range?

Answer (score 2):

I created a small extension for `String` which works for both `Index` based and `Int` based Ranges.

```
extension String {
    func NSRangeFromRange(swiftRange: Range<Index>) -> NSRange {
        let start = swiftRange.startIndex.samePositionIn(utf16)
        let end = swiftRange.endIndex.samePositionIn(utf16)
        return NSRange(location: utf16.startIndex.distanceTo(start), length: start.distanceTo(end))
    }
    func NSRangeFromRange(swiftRange: Range<Int>) -> NSRange {
        let indexRange = Range(start: startIndex.advancedBy(swiftRange.startIndex), end: startIndex.advancedBy(swiftRange.endIndex))
        return NSRangeFromRange(indexRange)
    }
}
```

Note: The function is on the `String` class because we need the strings `UTF16View` to convert between the Unicode-aware `Range<Index>` and the non-Unicode-aware `NSRange`.

Comment: There is one case in which this approach does not yield the correct results, and that is Emojis with skin tone modifiers. However this is a bug in Swift, as they report the length of characters like  incorrectly as 2 instead of 1: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1126558#1126558

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below function may help you

```
func findAndAddAttributeString(str: String, query : String) {

    let strASNSString = str as NSString

    println("employeeIdAsNSString, \(strASNSString)")

    var attributeDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [UIColor.grayColor(), UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)], forKeys: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName, NSFontAttributeName])


    println("attributeDictionary, \(attributeDictionary)")

    var attributedEmployeeId = NSMutableAttributedString(string: strASNSString, attributes: attributeDictionary)

    println("attributedEmployeeId = \(attributedEmployeeId)")

    var error:NSError?

    var regex = NSRegularExpression.regularExpressionWithPattern(query, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: &error)
    println("regex = \(regex)")

    var range = NSMakeRange(0, strASNSString.length)
    println("range = \(range)")

    regex.enumerateMatchesInString(strASNSString, options: nil, range: range, usingBlock:{ (textCheckingResult, MatchingFlags, unsafePointer) in
        println("textCheckingResult \(textCheckingResult.rangeAtIndex(0))")
        var subStringRange = textCheckingResult.rangeAtIndex(0)
        attributedEmployeeId.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: subStringRange)
        })
}
```

Comment: For UNICODE strings, .length may not work. countElements and advance methods to be used for finding exact ranges. This may not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a swift String to Swift NSString by

```
var strAsNSString = "வாங்க வாங்க வணக்கமுங்க" as NSString
```

And then you can create NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is not about creating NSMutableAttributedString. Its about finding the range for adding attributes.

s.string[4..6] will give the 2nd word for example

If I need to highlight that 2nd word, how do I specify the range using NSMakeRange - which expects range in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
let text = "வாங்க வாங்க வணக்கமுங்க"
var startOfWord = advance(text.startIndex, 5)
var endOfWord = advance(startOfWord, 5)
var range = startOfWord..<endOfWord
```

Even if some more work is required to figure out how far to advance (if you are looking for just one known word you can directly get it with NSRangeFromString)

Comment: The challenge is to construct NSRange from swift Range. How do we do that?  
  
`let text = "வாங்க வாங்க வணக்கமுங்க"`  
`var startOfWord = advance(text.startIndex, 4)`  
`var endOfWord = advance(startOfWord, 3)`  
`var highlightRange = startOfWord..<endOfWord` 
`text[startOfWord..<endOfWord]` 
  
`let attrText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text)
attrText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value:UIColor(red:0.0, green:1.0, blue:0.0, alpha:1.0), range:highlightRange)`